# cut command in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

My shell script look like this

```
 i="10 ID:794 A:TX-SPN S:0"
 A=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f 3| cut -d":" -f2`  # gives TX-SPN
 ID=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f 2|cut -d":" -f2`  # gives 794 
 sZeroCount=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f 1`  # gives  10
```

by above commands,I am able to get the values for A,ID,sZeroCount  variables, since the value for i contains only one entry, value of i not limited to 1 it may go upto 1000. Is there any better approach in which I can  obtain those values.

Comment: In reality you have not one line of input but up to 1000, is that correct?

Comment: I do recommend that you do not use old and deprecated back-tics, use parentheses like this. `A=$(echo $i | cut ........)`

Comment: Don't use `cut` for this sort of thing.`IFS=' :' read sZeroCount id_hdr ID A_hdr A _ <<< "$i"` works well for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

With an array. Split string `i` with separator space and `:` to array `a`:

```
i="10 ID:794 A:TX-SPN S:0"
IFS=" :" a=($i)
echo "${a[4]}" # TX-SPN
echo "${a[2]}" # 794
echo "${a[0]}" # 10
```

With chepner's bugfix:

```
i="10 ID:794 A:TX-SPN S:0"
IFS=": " read -a a <<< "$i"
echo "${a[4]}" # TX-SPN
echo "${a[2]}" # 794
echo "${a[0]}" # 10
```

Comment: This sets `IFS` globally, not just for the expansion of `$i`. `IFS=": " read -a a <<< "$i"` would be better (as it also avoids potential pathname expansion from being performed on `$i`).

Comment: @chepner   how both approach differs ? cut and the IFS in terms of execution?

Comment: @chepner: I don't agree with you that this (`IFS=" :" a=($i)`) sets IFS globally.

Comment: @Cyrus Have you tried `echo "$IFS"` following that line? It's not a pre-command modifier, because `a=($i)` is not a command.

Comment: @chepner: Now I see what you mean. I had tested `echo $IFS`.

Comment: Without the quotes, `$IFS` itself is subject to word splitting, so every character in it is subject to removal :) I should say, also, that `declare -p IFS` is a better way to examine the value of a variable.

Answer (score 1):

With this piece of code you can convert your line into a proper associative array:

```
declare -A dict
for token in START:$i  # choose a value for START that is not a key
do
  IFS=: read key value <<< "$token"
  dict["$key"]=$value
done
```

You can dump the result using `declare -p dict`:

```
declare -A dict='([A]="TX-SPN" [S]="0" [ID]="794" [START]="10" )'
```

And you can access the contents e. g. using this: `echo "${dict[A]}"`

```
TX-SPN
```

The start value (the `10` in your example) can be accessed as `"${dict[START]}"`.  Choose a value for `START` that doesn't appear as key in your input.

If you want to iterate over a lot of lines like your `$i`, you can do it like this:

```
while read i
do
  declare -A dict
  # ... add code from above ...
done < input_file
```

The advantage of using associative arrays is that this way you can access your values in a much more understandable way, i. e. by using the keys instead of some arbitrary indexes which can easily be mixed up and which need constant maintenance when changing your code.

Comment: Unquoted parameter expansions aren't safe in general, because they are subject to pathname expansion in addition to word-splitting.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for considering.  Which point are you talking about?  The `START:$i`?